# What is the probability of this event occurring at least once per day?

Tags: probability

There is a performance problem occurring with some databases, and I have a hypothesis about what is happening. The validity of this hypothesis depends on the probability of something happening. I'm wondering if my reasoning and math below are correct. To simplify things, here is a similar scenario:

**SETUP**

There are 100 databases. 99 databases each has a unique name associated with it, however 1 database has 20 names associated with it. So:

```
database    name
1           A1
2           A2
3           A3
... 
99          A99
100         A100, A101, A102, ..., A119
```

Every minute, something queries ten random names with no names repeated, which means some database(s) is/are being queried.

**QUESTIONS**

What is the probability that all ten queries in any given minute end-up querying database 100 (the one with 20 names)? What is the probability of this occurring at least once per day?

**REASONING**

There are 119 names, where 99 of those names are associoated with some database other than database 100, and 20 of those names are associated with database 100. For a single query, there is a 20 out of 119 chance a name associated with database 100 is chosen. The probability that all ten random queries lead to database 100 is (since once a name is chosen it cannot be chosen again):

$(20/119) * (19/118) * (18/117) * (17/116) * (16/115) * (15/114) * (14/113) * (13/112) * (12/111) * (11/110) = X $ (super tiny number)

The probability that this super tiny number $X$ happens at least once per day is $1 - X^{1440}$   (since it runs every minute and there are 1440 minutes per day). $1 - X^{1440} \approx 1$, which means it's virtually guaranteed to happen at least once per day.

Is my logic and math sound? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your $X$ is correct, but:

$Prob(\text{it never happens in a given day}) = Prob(\text{it doesnt happen in a given minute})^{1440}=(1-X)^{1440}.$

So: $Prob(\text{it happens at least once in a given day}) = 1 - (1-X)^{1440}$.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the feedback. :)